# Setiosflags is not recognized

Tags: c++, formatting

I'm trying to compile this but I get the error `error: ‘setioflags’ was not declared in this scope` which sounds like its trying to recognize it as a variable. This is an example I copied straight from my textbook, checked it over several times and can't find an error. Am I overlooking something? I'm on a mac if that makes a difference, I know the `<conio.h>` library doesn't work because of that, but `<iomanip>` is recognized

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int DISTRICTS = 4;
const int MONTHS   = 3;

int main() {
int d, m;
double sales[DISTRICTS][MONTHS];

cout << endl;
for(d = 0; d < DISTRICTS; d++)
    for(m = 0; m < MONTHS; m++)
    {
        cout << "Enter sales for district " << d+1;
        cout << ", month " << m+1 << ": ";
        cin >> sales[d][m];
    }

cout << "\n\n";
cout << "                       Month\n";
cout << "               1       2       3";
for(d = 0; d < DISTRICTS; d++)
{
    cout << "\nDistrict " << d+1;   
    for(m = 0; m < MONTHS; m++)         // Display array values
        cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) // Not exponential
        << setioflags(ios::showpoint)   // Always use poin
        << setprecision(2)              // Digits to right
        << setw(10)                     // Field width
        << sales[d][m];                 // Get number from array
}   // end for(d)
cout << endl;
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`setiosflags`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setiosflags/). Note the extra **s** in there. Your spelling is different on the second call.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes I just need a second set of eyes